# allow java plugin on internet explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer

I have customers who can't properly access their web application requiring java plugin to be enabled on internet explorer. This application requires the latest version ov java running (8u25 at the moment), but even verifying via control panel that it is correctly installed it is often difficult to check wether internet explorer is blocking the execution or not.

with other browser it is simple to see if plugins are blocked or not but on ie11 I have dome troubles.

could anyone enlighten me on what can I do to configure correctly ie11 to allow access to java plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether java plugin in enabled in your internet browser

Open your browser

**Tools -> Internet Options -> Security tab**

select the Custom Level button

Scroll down to Scripting of Java applets

Make sure the **Enable radio button** is checked

Click OK to save your preference and then check the issue

If issue persists please reset your internet browser

**Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced Tab -> Reset**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I enable Java in my web browser?

> **Internet Explorer**
>
> - Click Tools and then Internet Options
> - Select the Security tab, and select the Custom Level button
>
>   [image]
> - Scroll down to Scripting of Java applets
> - Make sure the Enable radio button is checked
>
>   [image]
> - Click OK to save your preference

Source [How do I enable Java in my web browser?](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Widows Control Panel, Select All Control Panel Items, Then Select Java, Go to Security, at the Bottom of the Screen Click Edit Site List, Add the Site that you got the error with, Test